# Quick editable view of 100 last rows (eg. in new tab) of large spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets

I have **large google spreadsheet** eg. thousands of rows and it's loading time may be longer than small spreadshet. Also usually I need only to see and work with **latest 100 rows**.

Is possible to **create view**, eg. new tab with only last 100 rows from another tab?

Both tabs should be synced for edit and also for adding new rows *(So that after adding new row to second tab, it will add row also to first and vice versa)*.

Example of source:

```
Name  | Value
-------------
First | 1
Sec   | 2
...
PrevL | 5000
Last  | 5001
```

Example of new sub-view:

```
Name  | Value
-------------
Xyz   | 4901
...
PrevL | 5000
Last  | 5001
```

Answer (score 1):

The following piece of code will create an editable 'view'.

### Code

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var v = 'VIEW', d = 'DATA', sRow = 100, sCol = 26;

function onOpen() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu("View")
    .addItem("Create view", "createView")
    .addItem("Update source", "updateSource")
    .addToUi();
}

function createView() { 
  var view = ss.insertSheet(v), data = ss.getSheetByName(d), width = data.getMaxColumns();
  view.deleteRows(sRow, (view.getMaxRows() - sRow));
  width < sCol ? view.deleteColumns(width, (sCol - width)) : view.insertColumnsAfter(sCol, (width - sCol));
  return setData(v, d);
}

function updateSource() {
  setData(d, v);
  ss.deleteSheet(ss.getSheetByName(v));
}  

function setData(source1, source2) { 
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  return ss.getSheetByName(source1).getRange('1:100').setValues(
    ss.getSheetByName(source2).getRange('1:100').getValues()
  );
}
```

### Explained

1. First a menu item is created ("View"), with two options.
2. The *createView* function inserts a new tab with only 100 rows and the same amount of columns the source tab has.
3. The *updateView* function re-writes the data to the source range (only 100 rows of course) and deletes the view tab.

### Example

I've created an example file for you: **[Quick Edit View](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1l5YpE7Xbe9I4gtOIBTIVryTI-memkvbeWu2MJhpp7DQ/edit?usp=sharing)**
Either make a copy of the example sheet or paste the code in your script editor (*Tools > Script editor...*) and press the authentificatie button to authenticate the script.

Perhaps it is wise to create a copy before you go berserk....